# django 1.3 admin.py not updating

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm having trouble with my admin panel not changing from default when viewing a model.

No matter what I add to the `SnippetAdmin` class nothing changes in the list view or edit view.

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from snippets.models import Snippet

class SnippetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('text', 'url')

admin.site.register(Snippet, site=SnippetAdmin)
```

If I remove the `register` command the model is removed from the admin panel as expected.

If I rename the class `SnippetAdmin` to `SnippetAdmin1` it invokes an error when trying to view the admin panel, proving the class is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please register your `ModelAdmin` like this:

```
admin.site.register(Snippet, SnippetAdmin)
```

The `site` named parameter is used for something completely [different](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects).